# Question about group theory and order of elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $G$ be a group and $x, y \in G$. Prove that $ord(x)=ord(y^{-1}xy).$

Let $n,m$ be integers such as $x^n=1$ and $(y^{-1}xy)^m=1$.

$x^n=(y^{-1}xy)^m=y^{-1}x^my=1$

I'm not sure how should I continue from here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$y^{-1}x^my=1 \Rightarrow x^my=y \Rightarrow x^m=yy^{-1}=1$

Comment: Note that the imlications go the other way as well.

Answer (score 2):

We have

$$(y^{-1}xy)^k=e\iff y^{-1}x^ky=e\iff x^k=e$$

then $ord(x)=ord(y^{-1}xy)$.

Comment: I'm sorry for my ignorance, but why is $(y^{−1}xy)^k=e$?

Comment: I proved the above result for every $k$. Now take the minimum to find the order and then you get the result.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $n$ is such that $x^n=1$. Then $(yxy^{-1})^n=yx^ny^{-1}=yy^{-1}=1$. Suppose conversely that $(yxy^{-1})^n=yx^ny^{-1}=1$. Then $yx^n=y$, $x^n=1$. Hence the result follows.